# sql server restrict query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I Use SQL Server 2012 and want to restrict my user to execute update query and delete query with condition. If user want to update or delete all rows of table, use `Where 1=1` condition.

I want trust from my users and reduce wrong query.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for DENY option? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258829%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Comment: @RahulTripathi. No I want to restrict DLM. Your link is for deny DDL.

Comment: You want to allow users to delete some records but not all? What if they want to delete 99,999 records out of 100,000? Or do you want to deny write operations alltogether? Give them the `db_datareader` role but not the `db_datawriter` one.

Comment: You can't. There's no facility to intercept the compilation, and if you try to prevent this in a trigger, I seem to remember it's pretty difficult to actually get hold of the text of the command that caused the change and then you'd have to parse it yourself.

Comment: I want to trust that my user, use condition in his query. I cant get executed query in trigger.

Comment: @ElectricLlama. User can delete all rows. but with this query 'Delete From TableName Where 1=1'.

Comment: INSTEAD OF triggers might help you, but more likely you'll properly need to tunnel your users through a gateway that parses the query.

Comment: What about `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SomeTableWhichMayBeEmptyOrNot)`